# Robust method of getting the first template parameter

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, type-traits

Assuming a template with a type-only list of template parameters, the following type trait can extract the first type argument:

```
template<typename T>
struct front {};

template<template<typename...> typename C, typename FirstT, typename... Args>
struct front<C<FirstT, Args...>> {using type = FirstT;};

template<typename T>
using front_t = typename front<T>::type;

template<typename...> struct foo{};

using std::is_same_v;
static_assert(is_same_v<front_t<foo<int, double>>, int>); // Ok
static_assert(is_same_v<front_t<foo<int, double>>, double>); // Fail (as expected)
```

This, however, doesn't work with templates that have value parameters:

```
using std::array;
static_assert(is_same_v<front_t<array<int, 5>>, int>);
// error: no type named 'type' in 'struct front<std::array<int, 5> >'
```

Ok, so now I need to take into account any value parameters too:

```
template<typename T>
struct front {};

// First parameter is a type, other parameters are types
template<template<typename...> typename C, typename FirstT, typename... Args>
struct front<C<FirstT, Args...>> {using type = FirstT;};

// First parameter is a type, other parameters are values
template<template<typename, auto...> typename C, typename FirstT, auto... Args>
struct front<C<FirstT, Args...>> {using type = FirstT;};

// First parameter is a value, other parameters are types
template<template<auto, typename...> typename C, auto FirstA, typename... Args>
struct front<C<FirstA, Args...>> {constexpr static const auto value = FirstA;};

// First parameter is a value, other parameters are values
template<template<auto...> typename C, auto FirstA, auto... Args>
struct front<C<FirstA, Args...>> {constexpr static const auto value = FirstA;};

// Avoid ambiguity if there's only a single type parameter
template<template<typename...> typename C, typename FirstT>
struct front<C<FirstT>> {using type = FirstT;};

// Avoid ambiguity if there's only a single value parameter
template<template<auto...> typename C, auto FirstA>
struct front<C<FirstA>> {constexpr static const auto value = FirstA;};

template<typename T>
using front_t = typename front<T>::type;

template<typename T>
const auto front_v = front<T>::value;

template<typename...> struct foo{};
template<auto...> struct bar{};

static_assert(std::is_same_v<front_t<foo<int>>, int>); // Ok
static_assert(std::is_same_v<front_t<foo<int, double>>, double>); // Fail (as expected)
static_assert(std::is_same_v<front_t<std::array<int, 5>>, int>); // Ok
static_assert(front_v<bar<5, 4>> == 5); // Ok
static_assert(front_v<bar<5, 4>> == 4); // Fail (as expected)
```

But then I try some more mixin':

```
template<typename, typename, auto...> struct baz{};

static_assert(std::is_same_v<front_t<baz<int, int>>, int>);
// error: no type named 'type' in 'struct front<baz<int, int> >'
```

This clearly is getting out of hand. Now, not only do I have to worry about mixing types with value parameters, I have to worry about the ordering of those parameters, and write a specialization for each combination of them. But all I want is the first of those parameters! The other ones shouldn't matter at all.

Finally, the question: Can I generically "ignore" any template parameters I don't really need for this type trait? By "generically" I mean to ignore both values and types.

Comment: Basically... nope. Metaprogramming works better if just everything everywhere is a type.

Comment: No love for template template parameters? :(

Comment: @Rakete1111 Absolutely not. If you want Haskell, you know where to download it. ;-)

Comment: @Barry I was afraid the answer would be just a plain "no" :). The corollary is that `std::array` doesn't mix very well with templates that have template template parameters...

Comment: @Rakete1111 they killed my father.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No.

As a general rule, using the way that arbitrary templates get their arguments as meaningful is a bad idea.  This is just one of the many problems you'll run into.

Template arguments are positional, but there is no univerally agreed upon meaning for each position.  Containers tend to have their first argument be the value type, but even that isn't true of associative containers (for whom the first two are synthesized into the value type).

```
template<class T>
using value_type = typename T::value_type;
```

that catches a bunch of cases.  If we want to get the key type on assiciative containers, we do:

```
template<class T>
using key_type = typename T::key_type;

namespace details {
  template<class...>using void_t=void;
  template<template<class...>class Z, class, class...Ts>
  struct can_apply:std::false_type {};
  template<template<class...>class Z, class...Ts>
  struct can_apply<Z,void_t<Z<Ts...>>, Ts...>:std::true_type {};
}
template<template<class...>class Z, class...Ts>
using can_apply = details::can_apply<Z,void,Ts...>;


template<template<class>class Z>
struct ztemplate1 {
  template<class T>
  using result = Z<T>;
};

template<bool b, template<class>class True, template<class> class False, class T>
using conditional_apply1 = typename std::conditional_t<
  b,
  ztemplate1<True>,
  ztemplate1<False>
>::template result<T>;

template<class X>
using container_first_type = conditional_apply1<
  can_apply<key_type, X>{},
  key_type,
  value_type,
  X
>;
```

and now `container_first_type<std::map<std::string, int>>` is `std::string`, while `container_first_type<std::vector<int>>` is `int` and `container_first_type<std::array<double, 7>>` is `double`.

[Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/17fda781750e30e4)

Comment: Thanks. My motivation is pure curiosity, so the first two paragraphs are already a great answer for me. The implementation of `container_first_type` seems too complicated, though. Specially that `can_apply` template, which seems to be a nightmare to implement. I answered with a [simpler version](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52281536/3854787), which I didn't edit in here because I fear it would change too much of your answer. Feel free to incorporate it if you want, and I'll delete it in that case.

Comment: @CássioRenan Implemented `can_apply`, it takes 4 lines of code.  :) . Note that your answer doesn't work, because `T::key_type` is an error before the conditional is evaluated if `T` doesn't have a key type.  `can_apply` and `conditional_apply` are tricky, because otherwise you have to manually do the tricks, and I'd rather hide the tricks in library code than in specific use.

Comment: @CássioRenan Live example added.  Had to modify solution slightly to deal with g++ and clang++'s respective quirks with template template parameters.

Answer (score 0):

There are no way to handle each cases.

What you can do as workaround:

- provide typedef inside the class

  ```
  template <typename T /*, */> class Foo {
      using first_type = T;
  }
  ```
- use only type, and possibly `std::integral_constant`

  ```
  Bar<int, std::true_type, std::integral_constant<int, 42>> bar;
  ```
- Only handle only common cases as `array`.